# How to print get method in javascript

Tags: printing, get

I want to print `mod` value in javascript document.write

for example my url is http://sitename.com/test.js?mod=57

now I want print 57 in `document.write`

```
document.write('<img src="http://utools.com/tools/mousse/mousse'+mod+'.png" />');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the value from URL Parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)

Comment: i want to use this cod in other age <script type='text/javascript' src="http://sitename.com/test.js?mod=56"></script>